# Blazemeter integrated with New Relic

Tags: jmeter, newrelic, blazemeter

I have written a script in Jmeter that simulates 20 users using the application for a ruby on rails web application. After integrating blazemeter with New relic, and after viewing the results, it shows that the test had encountered 4 error. Is there a way to find out where these errors have occured?

Comment: is there any errors you have caught in the development / production log?

Comment: Hi Charlie,    No errors in the logs!

Comment: I work for New Relic.   If the errors were captured by the new relic agent, they'll show up under the Events top navigation category, Errors sub-tab (when looking at your app overview in our UI).  The URL will be something like https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/X/applications/Y/traced_errors.  If they weren't captured by NR, they probably happened due to your webserver (not the java process, but whatever front-ends for it) or the JVM crashed.  If this isn't the case, open up a support ticket at http://support.newrelic.com and we can help you debug further.

Answer (score 0):

Where is it showing up that there were 4 errors?

If it's in BlazeMeter then you can download the JMeter .jtl file at the end of the test by clicking on the orange zip button in the test report (you must wait until the test is over for the zip button to appear).

You can view any requests that returned an error in the .jtl file (the .jtl file is the log file with every request made)

Comment: Hi Ophir, I am using the jmeter to create tests and upload them to blazemeter. I am viewing the results in the table that do not show any error in the report

Comment: Where exactly is it showing up that there were 4 errors, and what type of errors were they? 404? 500? bad connection?